# How to check NGINX configuration using Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, nginx

I need to programmatically check the NGINX configuration for correctness using bash. The result of the nginx -t command is assigned to a variable, and by the condition I compare the substring - syntax is ok with the result of the variable output. Unfortunately, it doesn’t work out. What am I doing wrong?

```
    CHECK="nginx -t"
    SUB='syntax is ok'
    if [[ "eval $CHECK" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
    echo "syntax is ok"
    else 
    echo "syntax is not ok"
    fi
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx -t` will provide a useful error code, so you can simply use:

```
if nginx -t > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "syntax is ok"
else 
  echo "syntax is not ok"
fi
```